# Android orientation change issue

Tags: android

The content of the webview is not displayed properly for some phones, when we change the orientation from portrait to landscape with the following java code:

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

What could be the workaround for this situation?

Thank you. Best wishes.

Comment: in the manifest, you declare `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` (or sensorLandscape, or any of the other values to pick from)

Comment: did you try putting `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in your config? What does is mean not displayed properly mean?